# How to go to a particular activity on list item click?

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I am developing an application in android in which i creating a list view of few items.
I want to call a class on each list item click.Here is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.listview.abc;

public class listview extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    public ListView lv1;
    public String[] names = { "Abc", "Xyz", "Pqr", "Jap", "Jay",
            "bla bla" };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
         if(position==0){
             Intent i = new Intent(this, abc.class);
             startActivity(i);
            //Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the first item in the list",
                //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed all other items in the list",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
         // else if(position==1){
            // start another activity here...
    }
```

The problem is that when i click the first item it crashes but the click on other item shows the message but when i click on the item for next activity it crashes 
i tried to follow this question of stackoverflow but it didn't work
{
[How to jump from ListView to next Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582757/how-to-jump-from-listview-to-next-activityclass-in-android)
}
here is some part of log cat

```
06-09 12:29:52.111: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(903): Shutting down VM
06-09 12:29:52.181: INFO/AndroidRuntime(903): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
06-09 12:29:52.181: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Start proc com.example.listview for activity com.example.listview/.listview: pid=910 uid=10039 gids={}
06-09 12:29:52.310: DEBUG/dalvikvm(903): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-09 12:29:54.670: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Displayed activity com.example.listview/.listview: 2616 ms (total 199904 ms)
06-09 12:29:55.249: DEBUG/dalvikvm(253): GC_EXPLICIT freed 176 objects / 12384 bytes in 3461ms
06-09 12:29:59.940: DEBUG/dalvikvm(125): GC_EXPLICIT freed 878 objects / 48664 bytes in 188ms
06-09 12:30:05.270: DEBUG/dalvikvm(262): GC_EXPLICIT freed 46 objects / 2240 bytes in 183ms
06-09 12:30:50.140: DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-09 12:32:52.731: DEBUG/dalvikvm(120): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9850 objects / 473648 bytes in 1222ms
06-09 12:35:50.171: DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-09 12:40:50.240: DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-09 12:45:50.311: DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

And the menifest File is

**

> **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>       package="com.example.listview" android:versionCode="1"
>       android:versionName="1.0">
>       <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
>           <activity android:name=".listview" android:label="@s tring/app_name">
>           
>               <intent-filter>
>                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>               </intent-filter>
>           </activity>
>     
>           <activity android:enabled="true" android:name="abc" />
>       </application>
>       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
>            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>     </manifest>
```

**

**

Please have a look at the code and help me out

Thanks in advance..

Comment: show your logcat message here .

Comment: Better if you extend `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`

Comment: @Frosty  my application simply crashes if i use ListActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you correctly register `abc.class` as an Activity in  your AndroidManifest.xml file? That would cause a crash.

Comment: here is the menifest Femi Is it fine                                                                                                         <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
   </activity>
  
  <activity android:enabled="true" android:name="abc" />
 </application>
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

</manifest>

Comment: The log output you posted does not appear to have the actual crash: can you post the log file with the crash in it? Also, post abc.class, as that is clearly having errors.

Comment: @ femi there was problem in my abc file Now the abc class has been  called Thanx for help

Answer (score 3):

```
public class ListItemIntent extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {   
    ListView lv1;
    String[] names = { "Abc", "Xyz", "Pqr", "Jap", "Jay", "Blabla" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (arg2) {
            case 0:
                intent= new Intent(this,Abc.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 1:
                intent=new Intent(this,Xyz.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 2:
                intent=new Intent(this,Pqr.class);
                startActivity(intent);  
                break;
            case 3:
                intent=new Intent(this,Jap.class);
                startActivity(intent);      
                break;
            case 4:
                intent=new Intent(this,Jay.class);
                startActivity(intent);          
                break;
            case 5:
                intent=new Intent(this,Blabla.class);
                startActivity(intent);          
                break;  
            default:
                break;
        }       
    }
}
```

for each class you have to add Activity in Androidmanifest.xml . and manifest like..

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".ListItemIntent"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Abc"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Blabla"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Jap"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Jay"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Pqr"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Xyz"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change Below in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name=".abc" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

also add below line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

then try it.

If not success the check below link.

[DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163375/debug-sntpclient60-request-time-failed-java-net-socketexception-address-fami)

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/117360/javanetsocketexception-address-family-not-supported-by-protocol

Comment: It didn't help Nik Should I attach my complete menifest file so might help you to suggest

Comment: Please attached complete AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name="com.something.something.abc" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ABC" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
<activity android:name="something.package.something.xyz" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.XYZ" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

just an example try that......