# How to create the activities for each items in a custom list

Tags: android

I had created a custom listview based on ArrayAdapter , then i need to create the Activities for each items in the custom listview, How to create the seperate activity for each item int the list.Any body has any idea please help me
Regards
Mithun

Comment: Check this Question [How to go to a particular activity on list item click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289227/how-to-go-to-a-particular-activity-on-list-item-click).

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to override the onListItemClick method in your ListActivity. Based on the position, you will construct an appropriate intent.

```
@Override 
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
{     
if (position == appropriate_condition) 
{        
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Bradford.class);        
 startActivity(intent);    
} 
}
```

If you need to access data associated with the item, the documentation provides this suggestion:

Subclasses can call `getListView().getItemAtPosition(position)` if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.

Comment: thank you for the reply, here appropriate_condition means the position number or any other method?

Comment: It is the position number if u know the number.. If u r getting it dynamically then u may have to add method there.