# How to start a new activity form ListView and give it multiple parameters

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, parameters

Below is my code which displays data in listview which is parses from json.
I want to start new activity when the user clicks on any item in the list.

I followed this url http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ and this is the json file  http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/

How to start a new activity when a user clicks on any item in listview and pass the remaining json values as parameters?

**Now my listview shows only names but i want to pass the remaining items, such as email, gender & mobile to the other activity.**

---

```
                           "id": "c200",
            "name": "Ravi Tamada",
            "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"






   public class NewsRowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

private Activity activity;
private List<Item> items;
private Item objBean;
private int row;
Context context;
public NewsRowAdapter(Activity act, int resource, List<Item> arrayList) {
    super(act, resource, arrayList);
    this.activity = act;
    this.row = resource;
    this.items = arrayList;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
        return view;

    objBean = items.get(position);

    holder.tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtText);


    if (holder.tvName != null && null != objBean.getName()
            && objBean.getName().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvName.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getName()));
         Intent intent=new Intent(context,TodayLunch.class);
         intent.putExtra("name", Html.fromHtml(objBean.getName()));
           context.startService(intent);

    }


    return view;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvName, tvCity, tvBDate, tvGender, tvAge;
}
}





                    package com.schoollunchapp;





public class SeletecDayofweek extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {


private static final String rssFeed = "http://192.168.2.100/jsonparsing.txt";

private static final String ARRAY_NAME = "student";
private static final String ID = "id";
private static final String NAME = "name";
private static final String CITY = "dish";
private static final String GENDER = "Gender";
private static final String AGE = "age";
private static final String BIRTH_DATE = "birthdate";


 ListView listMainMenu;
 List<Item> arrayOfList;
//MainMenuAdapter mma;
NewsRowAdapter objAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selectdayofweek);

    listMainMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainMenu2);
    listMainMenu.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    arrayOfList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    if (URLUtils.isNetworkAvailable(SeletecDayofweek.this)) {
        new MyTask().execute(rssFeed);
    } else {
        showToast("No Network Connection!!!");
    }

}

// My AsyncTask start...

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SeletecDayofweek.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return URLUtils.getJSONString(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (null == result || result.length() == 0) {
            showToast("No data found from web!!!");
            SeletecDayofweek.this.finish();
        } else {

            try {
                JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonArray = 
 mainJson.getJSONArray(ARRAY_NAME);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject objJson = 
 jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Item objItem = new Item();

                    objItem.setId(objJson.getInt(ID));
                    objItem.setName(objJson.getString(NAME));
                    objItem.setCity(objJson.getString(CITY));

objItem.setGender(objJson.getString(GENDER));
                    objItem.setAge(objJson.getInt(AGE));

objItem.setBirthdate(objJson.getString(BIRTH_DATE));

                    arrayOfList.add(objItem);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            setAdapterToListview();

        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
//  showDeleteDialog(position);




}


public void setAdapterToListview() {
    objAdapter = new NewsRowAdapter(SeletecDayofweek.this,   
R.layout.main_menu_item,
            arrayOfList);
    listMainMenu.setAdapter(objAdapter);
}

public void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(SeletecDayofweek.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

create array list like this

```
    public ArrayList<String> Id = new ArrayList<String>();
public  ArrayList<String> Name = new ArrayList<String>();
   public  ArrayList<String> Gender= new ArrayList<String>();


     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
         JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // here you can get id,name,city...

          Id.add(objJson.getInt("id"));

         Name.add(objJson.getString("name")); 
         Gender.add(objJson.getString("Gender"));




 //You need to use this code in the class where you have the view , 

// list item click 
     List_View.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        Intent i = new Intent(this, abc.class); 
// here arg2 is argument of onitemclick method
// this will pick the same item from array list that is clicked on list view 
                i.putExtra("key_name" , Id.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("key_name" , Name.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("key_name" , Gender.get(arg2));

                startActivity(i);       


                }




                });
```

can see this also

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1351248

and

http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android6ListViewSpinnerGridViewGallery.php

Comment: if your code is not in activity , or fragment , first you need to send the view object of listview to that class and the set click event there with proper context

Comment: i edit my full code now i have listview but how do i pass listview selected item (which is name form json list) and pas is other attributes like gender mobilen= number as parameter to toher activity

Comment: this is the code of adaprer only , can you shaow the whole class where the adpter is , the tutorial you have told has a click inside listactivity , if you are doing something different than that

Comment: no no thts rong ling http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.com/p/android-json-parsing-tutorial.html i follow this tutorial it was mistake

Comment: i just want list view only show nme and pass other attruibutes in other acitivity

Answer (score 0):

You start an activty with [startActivity(intent);](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

You set the OnClickListner on your ListView which is not included in your code so Im implying:

```
OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener (){

  @Override
  onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
      String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtText)).getText();
      Intent intent = new Intent(context,WhatEverYouWant.class);
      intent.putExtra("name",name);
      startActivity(intent);
  }

}

ListView listView = getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setOnItemClickListener (listener);
```

Comment: my class not extend activity

Comment: replace startService(intent); to startActivity(intent); if you want to start an activity

Comment: can see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289227/how-to-go-to-a-particular-activity-on-list-item-click

Comment: i see but i alrdy use list view in Activity class how do i pass parameter ??   i edit my code u can see then w8 1 min

Comment: i edit my code now so tell me how do i pass selected listview json item other attributes as parameter to other activity

Comment: ok, i edited it again this should work now, put it anywhere in your activity. BTW You edited my code, I rejected it, pls edit the original question not the answer.

Comment: well just copy my method onItemClick() to your activity

Comment: okbut what i wtite  instead of this Html.fromHtml(objBean.getName())  
in my  SeletecDayofweek classs so pass selected position other attribues as parameter to other activity

Answer (score 0):

I thing you shold put   `objJson.getString(NAME);` after `onItemClick......` to take the clicked item string name not other item

Comment: i do like this String myname;              
myname= objJson.getString(NAME);


public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
   long id) {
 // showDeleteDialog(position);
  
   Intent intent=new Intent(SeletecDayofweek.this,TodayLunch.class);
         intent.putExtra("name", myname);
           startActivity(intent);
  
  
 }

Comment: butis not pass current position of listview namr to other activity is show last name of listview to other activity

Comment: it is becuase the string object will always have the value of last object , first create a array list from all string values , then pick the value from arraylist it shall pick the same item by its index

Comment: + in your code you didn't Update parsed JSON data into ListView