# How to go to a new activity in ListView?

Tags: android

I have created a ListView and create A ,B and C in the list
now , i want when the user click A ,it led the user to a new activity called D. when  he clicks B, led him to new Activity called E,Clicks C and go to Activity F.
what should I do to accomplish that?

here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
                                            OnItemClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView support_device_list=(ListView)

findViewById(R.id.support_device_list);
    support_device_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------The new code

is it Like that?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
                                            OnItemClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView support_device_list=(ListView)

ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int  position,
long id) {
if(position==0)
{
Intent in=new Intent(lt18iActivity.this,lt18iActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
}
if(position==1)
{
Intent in=new Intent(YourActivity.this,ActivityB.class);
startActivity(in);
}
if(position==2)
{
Intent in=new Intent(YourActivity.this,ActivityC.class);
startActivity(in);
}
} 
});
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Implement `OnItemClickListener` on your `ListView` and start activity in that.

Comment: #rico chu This type of question already asked .Please search on Google

Comment: I SEARCH IT ON GOOGLE but i dont understand why is saying?

Comment: i dont know how to put them in my code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395060/how-to-start-new-activity-in-listview-item-click

Comment: @Jagjit Singh thx i will try it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int  position, long id) {
  if(position==0)
{
Intent in=new Intent(YourActivity.this,ActivityA.class);
startActivity(in);
}
if(position==1)
{
Intent in=new Intent(YourActivity.this,ActivityB.class);
startActivity(in);
}
if(position==2)
{
  Intent in=new Intent(YourActivity.this,ActivityC.class);
startActivity(in);
}
} 
});
```

Comment: better to use else for other cases with if . If you dont for example all other cases will be checked

Comment: can i create a string array and put /                                                                    Intent in=newIntent(YourActivity.this,ActivityA.class);/                            Intent in=newIntent(YourActivity2.this,ActivityB.class);?

Comment: @ricochu just give a try

Comment: Position 0 is string array name or <item>string</item>?

Comment: i said using   an i create a string array and put / Intent in=newIntent(YourActivity.this,ActivityA.class);/ Intent in=newIntent(YourActivity2.this,ActivityB.class);?  this it cant work