# Dynamic layout template

Tags: android, listview

In my `MainActivity`, which extends `ListActivity`, i populated a `ListView` and what I want to do in the `OnListItemClick` event is I want to go to the same layout every time, but based on which item I clicked, I want to display different data, more specifically change the image on the `ImageView` in the latter layout.

Comment: Do you want to start another `Activity` with the `ImageView` based on the clicked item?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Take a look at this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289227/how-to-go-to-a-particular-activity-on-list-item-click, this must help you to achieve your objective.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from one activity to another using a Bundle with the Intent to launch the new activity.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, YourOther.class);
Bundle extras = myIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString(key, value);
```

Or, you can use a shortcut method on the Intent itself.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, YourOther.class);
myIntent.putExtra(key,value);
```

Then in the receiving activity, you take the data out of the Bundle within the Intent doing something like this.

```
Bundle myBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String value = myBundle.getString(key)
```

**Note:** The key is the only thing that has to be a String, the values can be any of the primitive data types. There is a method in the bundle for every time.

```
bool value = myBundle.getBoolean(key)
int value = myBundle.getInt(key)
...
```